# Drupal site received url request embedding suspicious codes presuming attempt of hacking

Tags: drupal-7

I found a url request having suspicious code to one of my Drupal site. Will someone explain what will be the depth of this code and advise any precautions to be taken. Code:

```
function (){try{var _0x5757=["/x6C/x65/x6E/x67/x74/x68","/x72/x61/x6E/x64/x6F/x6D","/x66/x6C/x6F/x6F/x72"],_0xa438x1=this[_0x5757[0]],_0xa438x2,_0xa438x3;if(_0xa438x1==0){return};while(--_0xa438x1){_0xa438x2=Math[_0x5757[2]](Math[_0x5757[1]]()*(_0xa438x1 1));_0xa438x3=this[_0xa438x1];this[_0xa438x1]=this[_0xa438x2];this[_0xa438x2]=_0xa438x3;};}catch(e){}finally{return this}}
```

Site returned page not found error and I observed no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this code through a beatifier and you will receive:

```
function () {
    try {
        var _0x5757 = ["/x6C/x65/x6E/x67/x74/x68", "/x72/x61/x6E/x64/x6F/x6D", "/x66/x6C/x6F/x6F/x72"],
            _0xa438x1 = this[_0x5757[0]],
            _0xa438x2, _0xa438x3;
        if (_0xa438x1 == 0) {
            return
        };
        while (--_0xa438x1) {
            _0xa438x2 = Math[_0x5757[2]](Math[_0x5757[1]]() * (_0xa438x1 1));
            _0xa438x3 = this[_0xa438x1];
            this[_0xa438x1] = this[_0xa438x2];
            this[_0xa438x2] = _0xa438x3;
        };
    } catch (e) {} finally {
        return this
    }
}
```

First, let's rename some variables and decrypt the array of strings in the third line. I've renamed `_0x5757` to `arr` and escaped the hex-chars within the array. That gives you:

```
    var arr = ["length", "random", "floor"],
```

So here we have a list of functions that will be used shortly. Substitute the strings in and rename the variables and you will receive:

```
function () {
    try {
        var arr = ["length", "random", "floor"],
            length_func = "length",
            rand_number, temp;
        if (length_func == 0) {
            return
        };
        while (--length_func) {
            rand_number = Math["floor"](Math["random"]() * (length_func 1));
            temp = this[length_func];
            this[length_func] = this[rand_number];
            this[rand_number] = temp;
        };
    } catch (e) {} finally {
        return this
    }
}
```

Notice how there is a syntax error in the script when generating a random number.

```
* (length_func 1)
```

with `length_func = "length"` is not valid JavaScript syntax, so the code is actually not functional. I can still make a guess on what it was supposed to do: If we remove the obfuscation of calling a function by doing `Math["floor"]` instead of  `Math.floor()` the important lines are

```
        while (--length_func) {
            rand_number = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( length 1 ));
            temp = this.length_func;
            this.length_func = this.rand_number;
            this.rand_number = temp;
        };
```

It seems that it tries to compute a random integer using `Math.random()` and `Math.floor()`, then swaps the contents of the variables `length_func` and `rand_numerber`, all wrapped in a `while(--length_func)` loop. There's nothing functional here or anything that makes sense. An attempt at an infinte loop hanging the browser maybe? The code is, as it stands, non-functional. It even fails to generate a random number, because `Math.floor()` will always round-down the inputted float, and `Math.rand()` will generate a number within 0.0 to 1.0, so nearly always something slightly below 1.0, therefore `rand_number = 0` for most of the time. The multiplication with the `rand()` output with the `length_func 1` maybe should have made the number bigger, but the syntax is invalid. When I use my browser's console to execute `length`, it gives me `0`, when I try to do `length(1)`, then `length is not a function`, the only `length` that makes sense here is a string-length or array length, but then it would have to explicitly be `"someString".length`. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and detailed advise. I got relaxed after reading your reply. One question I have in my mind: If someone rectify the mistakes you pointed out, will it be functional to harm a drupal site. Is there any posibilities based on your reply?

Comment: If this code was sent to your drupal page, it was most likely an attempt to scan for a XSS (cross-site-scripting) vulnerability. This is JavaScript code, so it will be executed on the client's side. The goal is that JavaScript will be sent to the website, then that javascript executes in the person's browser directly (reflected XSS), or the JavaScript payload gets stored as a comment and is delivered to every client viewing your page (stored XSS). Though the code may be non-functional and highly obfuscated, the attacker just wanted to send *some* code to your page and see how it reacts to it.

Comment: Also the obfuscator used is probably that one: https://javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx (Naming of the variables are the same, `this[..]` style, function's names get stored in a string-array at the beginning)

Comment: Thank you once again. I think Rules will be the effective solution for blocking obfuscated codes as url in drupal or will you please suggest else.

Comment: Trying to do filtering on the URL before the data reaches the application can ofcourse be done (a good way to determine attacks), however, once your filters fail, the web-app should still resist an XSS attack in this case. So, your first priority should be to harden all web-apps sothat JavaScript can never be injected (stored/reflected) as your first line of defense, then think about additional filters.

Comment: Yes, agree with you. I got your point. I appreciate your advise. Little hard work required in this regard. Let me think about it. I'll comeback later. Have a great day.