# unexpected POST parameter received

Tags: javascript

I have an AJAX webservice, and a web page JavaScript that POSTs some information which is processed by some PHP code, and returns some new data to the caller.

Being paranoid, on the server I check the POST parameters I receive, and refuse to work if any of the parameters I expect are not there, but also, if I have been passed any parameters I am not expecting.  If that happens, I log the request.

And then it happened - in addition to the parameters I was expecting, from an Apple MAC Safari came an additional parameter, called "_sfl" (_SFL in lower case).  Even more curious - it contained some obfuscated immediate JavaScript function.

I'm not sure if it's etiquette to post the code of this function, which seems to do something with length, random and floor, but "it's not anything I've done" so I am curious how it has managed to get into the parameter block I sent, and how it's likely to be (accidentally?) executed and therefore exploited.

I presume something in the browser, has caused this to occur, but it's not of my doing.

Anyone come across anything this before?  Or know how I can protect myself so it doesn't happen?

-Monathan

Comment: This question doesn't really have an answer does it? I am suspecting that the user had some malicious extension or something similar that is probably broadcasting some info waiting for someone who can understand it to receive it *shrugs*. Besides that, I really don't know, haven't seen a browser do that myself, but then again, I haven't been sniffing all the POST data on my production websites to catch anything like this

Comment: the argument name doesn't ring a bell. How if you post the JS-function to see, wether it may be some ordinary JS that maybe got into crossfire or so, or if it tries to exploit you

Comment: By any chance, is [this](http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/?results=b98db5b80f6685ec258ebc64ed5b0221) the post data you received?

Comment: Possibly some tracking software installed on the Mac.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33186634

Comment: Spot on Siguza - that's the code!